# What Sql Drivers are in Azure Devops Build Agents?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a Node app that I need to run in Azure Devops Pipelines - it needs to connect to SQL Server (on a VM, also in Azure). It uses 'msnodesqlv8' to talk to SQL Server.

The connection string looks like:

```
Server=dns.name.here,1433;Database=mydb;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Extraction in DevOps;
```

Everything runs fine locally (obviously!) but the app fails when built and run in Pipelines with the following error:

```
Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

The VM image is 'windows-latest' which I would have thought would include the necessary bits to talk to a SQL Server.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

You can check this with a simple powershell `Get-OdbcDriver`.

Just run this as a step in ADO pipeline or release.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (32-bit & 64-bit) is available on windows-latest agents (as of writing, windows-2019 is the latest)